# Loading one file from XML root based on child value

Tags: php, xml

I have an xml feed which I am extracting using PHP, i have the code written to find the values I need and display correctly on the page.

XML code is:

```
<Agents>
   <Agent>
      <id></id>
      <description></description>
      <name></name>
   </Agent>
</Agents>
```

PHP Code

```
<?php
$url  = "urlgoeshere";
$xml  = simplexml_load_file($url);

for ($html = "", $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    $id          = $xml->Agent[$i]->id;
    $name        = $xml->Agent[$i]->name;
    $description = $xml->Agent[$i]->description;

    $html .= "<h1>$id</h1><h2>$name</h2><p>$description</p>";
}

echo $html;
```

This is set to load 11 agents which works fine but I want to change this and load only one specific Agent based on its id.

So for example if an agent has an id of 1200 on the xml field I want to find that and load only that one Agent but can't seem to work out an easy way to do this.

Comment: And your programming question is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use an `if` condition with a `continue`

```
$idToFind = 1200;
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $id = $xml->Agent[$i]->id;
    if ($id != $idToFind)
        continue;
    else {
        $name = $xml->Agent[$i]->name;
        $description = $xml->Agent[$i]->description;
        $html .="<h1>$id</h1><h2>$name</h2><p>$description</p>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly

Comment: If I wanted to show all of the results but exclude a specific id what would I need to amend?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. Either you filter client-side (in your code) or you filter server-side.

**Server side**

If you request the XML file e.g. from a [RESTfull service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) you might want to pass a parameter directly to your request.
Instead of requesting `example.com/agents.xml` you can maybe request `example.com/agents/1.xml` or something like that. In that case you have to check the API you request the XML file from. The pro for this type of filtering is, that you have to load a smaller xml file with less data and traffic.

**Client side**

If you are unable to filter the data on the server side, you need to check it in your PHP code. The simpelest option would be to add an `if` statement in your loop. And since you are talking about 1200 agents it might be the easiest aswell. In case you have to load more entries or speed and efficiency is required for your application you might want to use another XML parser. The SimpleXML class loads the whole file into the CPU. I have written a relatively efficient way [to parse an XML file with the XML Reader](https://gist.github.com/ferdynator/644a0cfedea3c9072546) which is more efficient and requires less memory. Feel free to edit the example to fit your needs.

Comment: thanks will look at this option also